# SQLite count(*) in while clause

Tags: sqlite, count, calendar

I have a calendar table in which there are all the dates in the future and a workday field:

fld_date / fld_workday
2014-01-01 / 1
2014-01-02 / 1
2014-01-03 / 0
...

I want select a date which are n workday far from another date. I tried two ways, but i failed:

The 5th workday from 2014-11-07:

1.

```
SELECT n1.fld_date FROM calendar as n1 WHERE n1.fld_workday=1 AND  
(select count(*) FROM calendar as n2 WHERE n2.fld_date>='2014-11-07' AND n2.fld_workday=1)=5
```

It gave back 0 row.

2.

```
SELECT fld_date FROM calendar WHERE fld_date>='2014-11-07' AND fld_workday=1 LIMIT 1  OFFSET 5
```

It's ok, but i would like to change the 5 days constant to a field, and it's cannot (it would be inside a bigger select statement):

```
SELECT fld_date FROM calendar WHERE fld_date>='2014-11-07' AND fld_workday=1 LIMIT 1  OFFSET fld_another_field
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first query, the subquery does not refer to the row in `n1`.

You need a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT fld_Date
FROM Calendar AS n1
WHERE fld_WorkDay = 1
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM Calendar AS n2
       WHERE fld_Date BETWEEN '2014-11-07' AND n1.fld_Date
         AND fld_WorkDay = 1
      ) = 5
LIMIT 1
```

The subquery is extremly inefficient if there is no index on the `fld_Date` column.

You can avoid executing the subquery for every row in `n1` by adding another condition with an estimate of the result date (assuming that there are between about four to five work days per week, and using a few extra days to be sure):

```
...
WHERE fldDate BETWEEN date('2014-11-07', (5 * 4/7 - 10) || ' days')
                  AND date('2014-11-07', (5 * 5/7 + 10) || ' days')
  AND fldWorkDay = 1
  AND (SELECT ...
```

Comment: Thank You! It's working, but it's very-very slow (2 minutes). (I have dates til 2050). Is it possible fasten up somehow?